# Count the number of <br>'s with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I count the number of `<br>` tags from a `<pre>` element ?

(using jQuery)

Comment: hey John, I guess it's too long since you coded that so you can't remember right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("br", "pre").length
```

or replace the "pre" with the reference of the tag you need

Comment: You should also mention the (to me) more convinient way: `$('pre').find('br').length` or at least `$('pre br').length`

Answer (score 4):

Answer here http://jsfiddle.net/HBGzy/1/

**html code**

```
<pre id="myID">
    <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
</pre>
```

**jquery code**

```
$('#myID br').length;
```